# is there a bluetoooth device or kit that can accept text messages

Tags: bluetooth, device

I want to be able to send arbitrary messages from my iphone to the bluetooth device and have it display it.

I would like to know if there is something already commercially available or something that can be put together with a little bit of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [Arduino with bluetooth](http://www.arduino.cc/) and an [LCD](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/lcd/charlcd.html) for under $200.  The Arduino API is open source and very friendly.

Comment: thanks! that does look very interesting. I should also have mentioned my motivation for this as being too lazy to check my phone. I want to be able to wear this on my wrist or belt and have it vibrate and display messages. The Arduino looks a little too big...

Comment: ok, I dug into it a little more, it may work for me! 
thanks much!